# Not able to import CSV files into access database after updating from 2007 to 2019 (MS365)

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access, import-from-excel

We recently finally upgraded from office 2007 to MS365 (so office 2019) and since then the access database that we are using is no longer importing the files that it used to.  It has a form with a button to run the import that clears a few temp tables, then does text transfers to pull the data back into said temp tables then runs queries to move the data to main tables.

It was still an old mdb that I was able to import into a accdb as I was informed that newer versions don't like the old type.  Nothing has changed with the incoming files and everything else that I have checked seems to be working properly.  Below is the VBA that runs when the import button is pressed, it gives no errors and says complete but nothing imports.  The queries all run fine but the import does not.

Any help or direction is very much appreciated!

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()

On Error Resume Next

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

DoCmd.OpenQuery "del_Handle_temp"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "del_tracktype"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "del_FAIR_PA"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "del_FAIR_PL"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "del_FAIR_SU"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "del_FAIR_OS"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "del_FAIR_IS"
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "FAIR_PA", "H:\TrackData\Import\fair_pa.csv", False
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "FAIR_PL", "H:\TrackData\Import\fair_pl.csv", False
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "FAIR_SU", "H:\TrackData\Import\fair_su.csv", False
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "FAIR_OS", "H:\TrackData\Import\fair_os.csv", False
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "FAIR_IS", "H:\TrackData\Import\isa_mdf.csv", False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "trisuper_update"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_tracktype"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "FAIR_OS Update"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "FAIR_OS Update2"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "FAIR_OS Update3"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "FAIR_OS Update4"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "FAIR_OS Update5"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "FAIR_OS Update6"

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

DoCmd.Close acForm, "import"
DoCmd.OpenForm "Done"
End Sub


Private Sub Command2_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "Importmain"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "import"
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using the actual UNC path to the file instead of a mapped drive (i consider notusing true UNC path to bad bad practice for vba). Also, check to make sure you have "show extensions" selected in folder options as that will ruin your day .lol

Comment: "gives no errors" - you have "On Error Resume Next" so you will not see any errors even if they occur.

Comment: Yeah Tim points out something very important - on error resume next is awful - you should fix that.

Comment: @AaronOttwell do these csv's have filed names in them? If so the issue your setting "has field names"=false

Comment: Another issue you could be facing is the BOM setting of the csv file may be causing your vba code to bomb since field names wont match

Comment: Comment out "On Error Resume Next" line and see what error you get. Maybe even comment "Set Warnings" to see if there are any query failures. There is no need to open query objects that are just SELECT. I am guessing "qry_tracktype" is just SELECT.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I inherited this hot mess and got so focused on the import lines I totally passed over the On Error Resume line.  taking that out I was able to narrow down my issue and get it fixed.  Sometimes you just need another set of eyes.  Thanks again!